# is it possible to make rails 2 the default instead of rails 3 on my mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

Is it possible to make Rails 2 the default rails on my mac?

Thanks

Comment: There are two distinct unrelated questions here. It would be better if you ask them in separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wish to install rails 2, then specify the version you want when installing the gem

```
gem install rails-2.3.5
```

If you want to maintain different versions of rails, then you probably also want to maintain different versions of ruby. In that case, [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) is your friend.

Comment: 2.3.10 is the latest pre rails3 version

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need to have couple of rails env [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/) is always a good idea.

Comment: I should have a template somewhere which says "use rvm!!!" whenever anyone asks a question about: installing rails, installing ruby, installing gems etc...